# get value form simpledialog2 blank mode

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have used JQM SimpleDialog2 in my app. I am having one textbox and button in that dialog. i can't able to get the value from input while click on button in dialog. i have used blank mode.. Here is my code..  I am getting empty value from this code. please correct me.

```
<div id="myDialog" style="display:none"
            data-options='{"mode":"blank","top":"10%","headerClose":false,"blankContent":true}' 

<Center>please enter Your Amount here</center>
<input id="txtAmt" name="amy" value="" type="text" placeholder="Amount">

                <div data-role="navbar"  data-grid="a">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#" data-theme="a" id="submit" onClick="getAmount();">Submit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" data-theme="a" id="cancel" rel="close">Cancel</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

function getAmount()
                {

                    alert("amount: "+$("#txtAmt").val());
                }

Answer (score 0):

i didnt try this using SimpleDialog but this works just fine for me:

```
function getAmount(){
alert (document.getElementById('txtAmt').value);
}
```

By the way i would recommend using the built-in Popup-Dialog function instead of SimpleDialog. See here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/dialog/index.html